# Loadable macOS bundle symbol conflicts with symbol in a dynamic library

Tags: c++, macos, plugins, linker, dyld

We are developing a plug-in (loadable bundle) for Adobe Illustrator which uses Boost extensively. The plug-in is compiled as a `MODULE` CMake library. i.e. `add_library(ourplugin MODULE ...)`

This library links **statically** to Boost.

The host application (Adobe Illustrator) also uses Boost, albeit a different version, and the application bundle includes Boost as a framework.

When a function from our bundle is invoked, it calls some Boost serialization compiled functions. It turns out the dynamic linker uses Boost function from the framework that comes with the application, instead of the version that is present in the plugin binary itself, causing compatibility errors.

We could confirm the symbol is actually present in our bundle with `nm -gU --demangle ourplugin`

Is there a way to instruct the dynamic linker to always prefer symbols defined in the bundle, when they are requested from the bundle itself?